# Generating product URL with Product ID

Tags: powershell, foreach

Im trying to generate product URL with product ID. I did a `foreach` loop and it works. But it puts the ID in `@{}`.

```
foreach ($ID in $id) {
    $url = "https://MyUrl/" + $ID
    $Path =  $url 
    $Path
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
https://MyUrl/@{id=351}
https://MyUrl/@{id=348}
https://MyUrl/@{id=342}
https://MyUrl/@{id=293}
```

How can I delete `@{}` from the URL, or how can I generate a product URL with (if there are any other ideas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I found the solution
I had to add `.id` after `+$ID` 
It should look like this

```
ForEach ($ID in $id){
$url = "https://MyUrl/"  +$ID.id
$Path =  $url 
$Path
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just append `$ID.id`:

```
ForEach ($ID in $id){
$url = "https://MyUrl/" +$ID.id
$Path =  $url 
$Path
}
```

Comment: haha I posted right now my answer. But thank you anyway.